# SQL inject while allowing iFrames

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, code-injection

Is there a way to allow users to include iframes from specific websites while excluding those from unverified sites? I am doing a system that allows users to include iframes with their posts, however, doing this also opens my site to SQL injection.

Comment: Why would it open your site to SQL injection? Just escape everything and you should be good. Did you mean CSRF attacks?

Comment: Thing is when I escape everything the iframe just shows up as text.

Comment: iframes have nothing to do with sql injections

Comment: I may be mistaken about the terminology. What happens: When using htmlentities or htmlspecialchars the iframe just shows up as text. While using real_escape_string says, 'Access forbidden!', in the iframe.

Comment: What is the source of the iframe that says access forbidden? That shouldn't have anything to do with whether or not you're storing it in the database.

Comment: your error is coming from the domain origin policy (XSS), has nothing to do with SQL.

Comment: The iframes come from Soundcloud and Mixcloud.

Comment: So the iframes (hosted by soundcloud and mixcloud) are attempting to use javascript to access something from the parent window (your domain) and you have not set your server to allow for this (this is not something "turned on" by default, as it is a XSS risk).  This is causing the "Accessed Denied" error.

Comment: @CrayonViolent, SOP it's browsers feature, but 'Access forbidden!' is 403 response of server.

Comment: Thanks, really cleared things up!

Comment: One more question. Do you think the problem might also have to do with the fact I'm on Localhost and not a live server?

Comment: It is possible that the live server has different internet connectivity than the development server on localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct relation between iframes and SQL injections.

Just use [prepared statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) when inserting HTML code without modification. ([PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), [MySQli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php))

But i must aware you about [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). All your forms and action links must be with token.

Comment: I may be mistaken about the terminology. What happens: When using htmlentities or htmlspecialchars the iframe just shows up as text. While using real_escape_string says, 'Access forbidden!', in the iframe.

Comment: @BernieAllen, 1. do not use mysql_* extension. 2. Use prepared statements 3. 'Access forbidden' - it's message of foregin link site. So check your link.